Nginx returns index.js file as index.html
I have a location block set in the nginx file on the server:
location / {
    proxy_pass https://mineloadbalacner.elb.amazonaws.com; (not the actual name)
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

It forwards all requests to the AWS ALB (Application Load Balancer), which targets a service on ECS. This service also has nginx for serving static files, and it looks like this:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    root /var/app/www/html;

    location ~ ^/(.*) {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}

The problem occurs when I access the application through the official domain and check the index.js file in the network tab. I see the response, but it's the same as index.html. Additionally, the page I open this way is "blank," and I don't see the /static/ folder being loaded. However, when I try to access it directly through the ALB, I don’t have this issue, which means the ALB serves the files correctly.
I also get the following error in the console:
index.js: Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

But I actually expect this error in this situation where the index.js response is the index.html file.
Since the DNS is connected through Cloudflare, I tried purging the cache, clearing the local browser cache, directly accessing the JS file by its location, and similar things.
